# Ksql is not getting started. ksql-server-start: 32: exec: //bin/ksql-run-class: not found

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Am unable to start ksql. Its providing below error,

```
ksql-server-start: 14: Bad substitution
ksql-server-start: 32: exec: //bin/ksql-run-class: not found
```

zookeeper and kafka server is started successfully

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: What is your host OS? What version of ksqldb are you using?

Comment: Its UNIX, Ubuntu

Comment: What version? KSQL Docker image or not?

Comment: Its not Docker image. I downloaded the confluent-5.5.1-2.12.zip from confluent page

Comment: I suggest reaching out to https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues

Comment: Thank you. I have raised it. https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/5928

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Found the solution for this. There is a issue with the script, simple modification worked out. Thanks for introducing me to https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for the issue,

**ksql-server-start**

Script in ksql-server-start file has a code to export the path `$base_dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/.." && pwd )` and this code is not working executing via script. Changed the valuewith the actual path resolve the issue

```
$base_dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/.." && pwd ) #Existing

$base_dir=/path/to/confluent-5.5.1 # This resolved the issue
```

This has to be done on **ksql** script as well

Comment: `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"` should work if you are using bash