# Error: Could not find or load main class Folder.confluent-5.5.1-2.12.tar.confluent-5.5.1-2.12.confluent-5.5.1.logs

Tags: apache-kafka, cygwin, ksqldb

I am using cygwin on window.

and Running follows command on cygwin  for starting ksql server.

```
bash ksql-server-start .properties

Error: Could not find or load main class Folder.confluent-5.5.1-2.12.tar.confluent-5.5.1-2.12.confluent-5.5.1.logs
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194629/ksql-is-not-getting-started-ksql-server-start-32-exec-bin-ksql-run-class

Comment: After Modifying ksql-server-start file,  I face other errors like : ksql-server-start: line 32: E:/confluent-5.5.1-2.12/confluent-5.5.1/bin/ksql-run-class io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain: No such file or directory. @OneCricketeer what should need to do

Answer (score 0):

No Windows compatible scripts are provided with ksqlDB. You may be able to 'fix' the scripts that do come with it to work on windows.  Alternatively, you can just run ksqlDB and the CLI in docker, which is the supported routed for Microsoft windows.  See the [ksqlDB microsite](https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html) for instructions on how to get something up and running in docker, or the [Kafka examples microsite](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/).